# Oracle ORDS directory browsing wouldn't work

Tags: oracle, jetty

I am using Oracle ORDS 3.0.9 and try to enable the directory browsing but keep getting HTTP 403 forbidden error. This is my jetty-http.xml configuration in /standalone/etc folder and I run this command to start 'java -jar ords.war &':

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" 
"http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

<Call name="setInitParameter">
    <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed</Arg>
    <Arg>true</Arg>
</Call>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 0):

The setting is disabled for security.  If this is needed, my suggestion would be to deploy ORDS into tomcat where there's much more control over the webserver.